# How to do preprocess for all queries in VS2012 LightSwitch?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

It seems that VS2012 Light Switch has removed the [Table_Name]_All_PreprocessQuery option from the drop down menu of "Write Code" for a table in the designer which is available in VS2010 + Light Switch 2.0.

Can we do similar with VS2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The All_*PreProcessQuery* method has been deprecated in favor of the *Filter* method. However, even though it's no longer available in the *Write Code* dropdown, you can still write the method manually.

Comment: yes, I just found this out thru Beth Massi's "Perform Automatic Row-Level Filtering of Data" video. But anyway, thank you and I marked your answer as accepted